# phpRedis migration to cluster and consistent hashing

Tags: php, redis, phpredis

We are currently using `PhpRedis` extension and our code is written using the class `Redis` from the `PhpRedis`. But now we are migrating to a redis cluster.

Is it possible to use the Class Redis  to connect to redis cluster? or do we need to re-write our code and use the Class RedisArray?

We ll need to have consistent hashing too. We have added keys like this `{user}:1` so we can do consistent hashing later.

main problem is taking all the code written using the class `Redis` and changing it to `RedisArray`.

I am new to redis so please provide some advice

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a email reply from one of the author of PHPredis Nicolas. I thank him for taking the time for replying to me.

Hi,

I just want to start by clarifying that the RedisArray class does not provide a client library for [Redis Cluster](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial). It uses consistent hashing to distribute data to a set of independent Redis nodes, and provides a common interface so that developers can avoid having to write the distribution layer themselves.

Phpredis does not currently support Redis Cluster.

Addressing your questions:

- It is possible to connect to 4 redis servers with RedisArray.
- RedisArray provides consistent hashing and you can select which part
  of the key is to be used for the distribution.
- The RedisArray class has a few [limitations](https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis/blob/master/arrays.markdown#limitations). In particular, multi-key
  commands (e.g. ZINTERSTORE) are mostly executed on one node, but some
  do offer integrated distribution (e.g. DEL, MGET).

To learn more about the RedisArray class, please refer to the [documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis/blob/master/arrays.markdown).

**They have added support for Redis cluster now**
https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/blob/feature/redis_cluster/cluster.markdown#readme