# What are the differences between Redis, RedisArray and RedisCluster classes in PHP?

Tags: php, redis, redis-cluster

On my DEV machine I use Redis class which is works fine. On my LIVE server I use RedisArray and/or RedisCluster classes.

From [RedisArray docs](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/blob/develop/arrays.markdown#usage):

> Redis arrays can be used just as Redis objects.

From [RedisCluster docs](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/blob/develop/cluster.markdown#redis-cluster):

> For the majority of operations the RedisCluster class can act as a drop-in replacement for the Redis class without needing to modify how it's called.

Recently I've noticed a data loss on my LIVE server. I mean, when using RedisArray or RedisCluster sometimes some data disappears.
Is it a normal behavior for RedisArray/RedisCluster?
Is there a way to prevent a data loss?

Answer (score 2):

According to a [very similar question](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/issues/1614) in the PhpRedis' GitHub repository issues tracker:

> when you use Redis as caching and persisting is disabled, you have to use sharding (RedisArray) to avoid high traffic issues between backends and Redis.

Also, there's an email by one of the authors of PhpRedis replicated in [another question here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20540703/3136474). Please note that the question is almos 7 years old, but the answer was edited 5 years ago.

It seems like `RedisArray` supports client-side key sharding (introduced before Redis Cluster official support) and `RedisCluster` uses the official [Redis Cluster feature](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial).